# Why doesn't highcharts solidgauge charts scale the way I expect?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using a solidgauge chart from highcharts and appear to have scaling issues.
The basic issue is that I want to define a chart that can be resized and expect the graph to adjust to fit the space in the best way.
But sometimes the chart extends outside the container and sometimes the chart is smaller than it needs to be.

A test is in jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adrian_onesight/k2amdhL1/4/).

That test shows various versions of the chart:

- Chart test [A] = pane.size = 100% / container size = 400px x 400px.
- Chart test [B] = pane.size = 140% / container size = 400px x 400px.
- Chart test [C] = pane.size = 100% / container size = 400px x 300px.
- Chart test [D] = pane.size = 140% / container size = 400px x 300px.

The main chart options used are these:

```
{
        chart: {
          type: 'solidgauge'
        },
        credits: false,
        title: {
          text: 'Solid Gauge'
        },
        yAxis: {
          minorTickInterval: null,
          min: 0,
          max: 100
        },
        pane: {
          center: ['50%', '85%'],
          size: '140%', // ISSUE: problem scaling chart outside container
          //size: '100%', // ISSUE: problem with gap above gauge
          startAngle: -90,
          endAngle: 90,
          background: {
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
              y: 5,
              decimalPlaces: 1,
              units: 'rpm',
              borderWidth: 0,
              useHTML: true,
              format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ('black') + '">{point.y:.11f}</span><br/>' +
                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">rpm</span></div>'
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        }
      };
```

`Chart [A]` is OK, but if I use the same pane size (100%) and reduce the height (to 300px) to remove the gap between the title and the chart then I get `[C]` where the chart has been scaled down too small.
Similarly, `chart [D]` is OK, but if I use the same pane size (140%) and increase the height (to 400px) then the graph extends outside the container as shown in `[B]`.

Are there any options that I am missing that can be used to fix this problem, or am I going to have to dynamically adjust the chart based on container size (which I want to avoid) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read on highcharts forum here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33070

> Solid gauge is created from angular gauge. The background is one of
>   key elements that make the chart look like arc shaped solid gauge. If
>   you disable it you will see that options used for inner radius and
>   outer radius as well as size or center of pane are calculated for
>   circle, but the arc is used for visualization.

So, remove the `startAngle` and `endAngle` to see how the chart is scaled. As you can notice it is scaled as circle and arc is used only for visualization. That's why it is acting so strange, due to solid gauge architecture.

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mtevb2d3/

Comment: That makes sense when you put it in context. But is there any way to get rid of the space above or below if you are just using the 180 arc ? Obviously resizing the container will just scale the chart.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to set the chart height and width dynamically as the canvas size changes, unfortunately.

Comment: This is one approach, another is to change pane size when the chart size is lower than pane size. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Luy40bh/2/